# 3 spans next to each other

Tags: html, css

So ive been working on this site for college and ive been running into this problem, its been causing me frustration for the past hour or so.

I have these 3 images all sitting right next to each other on my index page. Now what im trying to achieve is 3 span tags / 3 p tags or 3 whatever will work to displayed directly below the 3 images with the same spacing and width as the images, basically 3 text boxes under the images.

Ive tried float:left, float:right, display:block, display:inline, display:block-inline, etc, etc.

Heres my code:

```
<!-- NEWS ICONS -->
<a href="#">
<img src="Images/news1.png" style="width:264px; height:263px; margin-left:29px; 
padding-bottom:5px;" alt="news1"/></a>

<a href="skateboards.html#creature">
<img src="Images/news2.png" style="width:357px; height:263px; padding-left:15px;
padding-bottom:5px;" alt="news2"/></a>

<a href="seanmalto.html">
<img src="Images/news3.png" style="width:264px; height:263px; padding-left:15px;
padding-bottom:5px;" alt="news3"/></a>


<span style="margin-left:30px; width:263px; display:block; background-color:#000;">
Content 1 Content 1 Content 1 Content 1 Content 1 Content 1 
</span>

<span style="padding-left:15px; width:356px; display:block; background-color:#000;">
content 2 content 2 content 2 content 2 content 2 content 2 content 2 content 2 
content 2 content 2 content 2 content 2 
</span>

<span style="padding-left:15px; width:263px; display:block; background-color:#000;">
content 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 content 3 
</span>
```

**ive just made the span's background black so I can identify and see them better.**

Thanks,
Miles

Comment: Wrap the image and the corresponding text into one container, and position the containers instead.

Comment: Seriously you are the best, thank you so much. It was so obvious haha. I guess thats what happens when you've staring at code for 8+ hours. I tunnel visioned very hard.

Comment: @user3024489 If that was the right answer then you should really accept it and give the rep credit.